# SQL 1 row twice

Tags: sql

I have SQL table what looks like:

```
+----------+-----------+
| ID       | Direction | 
+----------+-----------+
| 1        | left      | 
| 1        | null      | 
| 2        | left      | 
| 2        | null      | 
| 3        | null      | 
| 4        | left      | 
| 4        | null      |
| 5        | null      |
+----------+-----------+
```

I want to show each value only once:

- If there will be ID `1` with Direction `null` and `left`, then show only ID `1` with direction `left`.
- If there will be ID `1` only with `null` value, show it with `null` value.

[image]

Comment: Can `Direction` take on any other values?

Comment: No, only left value or null.

Comment: external image included into your question because it reveals useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a common table expression (cte):

```
with cte as 
(
    Your huge select...
)
select *
from cte t1
where t1.Direction = 'left'
  or not exists (select * from cte t2
                 where t2.kanbanid = t1.kanbanid 
                   and t2.Direction = 'left')
```

I.e. if your select has Direction 'left' for a kanbanid, return that row. Also return that row if same kanbanid has no Direction 'left' at all.

Comment: Still have both values (left and null) :(

Comment: Yes... Can be problem with tables? I have ID from different table than Direction.

Comment: Are there two tables involved??? Show us all tables involved, and some sample table data please.

Comment: That's much more complex. Will be back in a while.

Comment: I got this error: http://s9.postimg.org/hn6eh6ywv/error.png Hope i used it right.

Comment: Ok, i moved little forward. Now I'm getting error "Timeout"

Answer (score 1):

Why wont below query work:

```
select id,max(dir)
from #temp
group by id
```

below is test data:

```
create table #temp
(
id int,
dir char(10)
)

insert into #temp
select 1,'left'
union all
select 1,null
union all
select 2,null
union all
select 3,'right'
union all
select 3,null
union all
select 3,null


select id,max(dir)
from #temp
group by id
```

aggregate functions will ignore null,below is the output:

[image]

Comment: Images are blocked in my firewall ,so I cant see output.But as per description,you need one value if it has value other than null,if it has only null.then show null

Comment: Was about to post this same answer. But with SQL it is almost mandatory to talk about the specific DB used. This same solution worked for me on SQLite. Seems your DB is working fine too.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct  *,
row_number() over (partition  by id order by ,Direction )as row1 into #any_table
from #your_table_name

select * from #any_table
where row1 =1